# Wamp/Zend framework setting up virtual host setup

Tags: zend-framework, wamp

I have installed Zend framework on Wamp. However when I try to setup the virtual host - Apache fails to start when I restart the Wamp server after editing the httpd.conf  file. Sometimes after editing this file I get 403/forbidden error on Wamp splash screen as well.

- Apache version no is 2.4.2
- PHP version no is 5.4.3
- MySQL version no is 5.5.2
- Zend framework version no is 1.12.3.

Comment: When did you change in httpd.conf?

Comment: Yes supply the vhost configuration

Comment: Always avoid editing the original Apache config file. For virtual host configuration you can put them in the vhosts.conf file.